# Should I use Yield when writing my own extension?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I wanted to write an extension method (for using it in a fluent syntax) so that If a sequence is :

```
List< int> lst  = new List< int>(){1,2,3 };
```

I  want to repeat it 3 times (for example). so the  output would be  `123123123`

I wrote this :

```
 public static  IEnumerable<TSource>  MyRepeat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>  source,int n)
    {
         return    Enumerable.Repeat(source,n).SelectMany(f=>f);
    }
```

And now I can do this :

```
  lst.MyRepeat(3)
```

output :

[image]

**Question :**

Shouldn't I use Yield in the extension method ? I tried `yield    return`   but it's not working here. Why is that and should I use it.

## edit

After Ant's answer I changed it to :

```
public static  IEnumerable<TSource>  MyRepeat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>  source,int n)
    {
        var k=Enumerable.Repeat(source,n).SelectMany(f=>f);
        
                foreach (var element in k)
                {
                    yield   return    element;
                }
    }
```

But is there any difference ?

Comment: Explain what "not working" means.

Comment: @ant _Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>' to 'TSource'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)_

Comment: `yield return` is just used in low-level implementation, I think your code is OK.

Comment: @downvoter , Downvoting without any comment is not the spirit of SO.  - Reported.

Comment: The problem with your implementation is that you enumerate `source` multiple times. That's not possible for all enumerables.

Comment: `yield` has a downside: argument validation only happens on enumeration and not when you call the function.

Comment: @CodesInChaos do you mean that i'm enumerating it multiple times at my first example using repeat ? Also , can you explain you second comment about the downside. I didn't get it ( and of course- thank you)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Could you explain why you're saying that it's possible that an `IEnumerable` might not be enumerable multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the following *already returns* an IEnumerable:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(source,n).SelectMany(f=>f);
```

When you use the `yield` keyword, you specify that a *given iteration* over the method will return what follows. So you are essentially saying "each iteration will yield an `IEnumerable<TSource>`," when actually, each iteration over a method returning an `IEnumerable<TSource>`should yield a `TSource`.

Hence, your error - when you iterate over `MyRepeat`, you are expected to return a `TSource` but because you are trying to `yield` an `IEnumerable`, you are *actually* trying to return an `IEnumerable` from *every iteration* instead of returning a single element.

Your edit should work but is a little pointless - if you simply return the IEnumerable directly it won't be enumerated until you iterate over it (or call `ToList` or something). In your very first example, `SelectMany` (or one of its nested methods) will already be using `yield`, meaning the `yield` is already there, it's just implicit in your method.

Answer (score 2):

Ant P's answer is of course correct.

You would use yield if you were building the enumerable that is returned yourself, rather than relying on SelectMany.  eg:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int repeat)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)
        foreach(T item in items)
            yield return item;
}
```

The thing you yield is an *element* of the sequence. The code is instructions for producing the sequence of yielded elements.